# Refreshing a matplolib plot on a flask app after updating dataset

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, seaborn

I have been using the suggestion here:

[How to render and return plot to view in flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492197/how-to-render-and-return-plot-to-view-in-flask)

to create a plot in my flask app.

In the app I can update the actual values in the data set, and the plot updates respectively, BUT the 'previous plot line' does not. [image]

I tried saving the file as a static plot in a folder, but then the updated data is not refreshed.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: may be after adding the code in your question, we find some reasons. your methodology of storing new graph and represent that graph is good.

Comment: @Nour-AllahHussein I am using the code in the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found this [link](https://morioh.com/p/b8f24b983853) that offers a solution for my problem.

Basically, changing the basic code in the [link in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492197/how-to-render-and-return-plot-to-view-in-flask):

```
img = io.BytesIO() 
sns.set_style("dark")
plt.plot(df.Date, df.Value) 
plt.savefig(img, format='png', transparent = True) 
img.seek(0)   
plot_url = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode()
```

to:

```
fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6))
ax=sns.set(style="darkgrid")
sns.lineplot(df.Date, df.Value)
canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
img = io.BytesIO()
fig.savefig(img,transparent = True)
img.seek(0)
plot_url = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode()
```